# How do I use an external FBX object in Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, fbx

Is it possible to use an external `.fbx` object in Unity 3D the same way we can insert a picture?

Something like `myPath = "http://www.myserver.com/object/myobject.fbx";`?

Answer (score 3):

To load up a 3D model in `run time` from a server, you need to use `AssetBundles`. You create an AssetBundle and upload it to a server. You can then download that [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html) with the unity [WWW class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

There is a another way to do it, which is suggested [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/511957/how-to-add-models-dynamically-at-runtime-in-unity.html). In this solution you read the text file construct the model from that. Very difficult and time consuming.

Comment: Hi Esa , good information for me, the option AssetBundle is good , but testAsset is interesting also, thank you very much!!